# Si Bob ou Alice est/sont arrivé(s) ?

Tags: verbes, accord, conjonctions, coordination

Lorsque le sujet est formé d'une condition logique non exclusive, comment devrions-nous écrire cette phrase ?

Comment accorder le verbe être dans ces quatres différentes situations ?

> Si Bob ou Alice est arrivé ?
>
> Si Bob ou Alice sont arrivés ?
>
> Si seulement Bob ou seulement Alice est arrivé ?
>
> Si Bob et Alice sont arrivés ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les quatre phrases proposées sont correctes. En effet, lorsqu'il a plusieurs sujets coordonnés, le verbe est généralement conjugé au pluriel, mais pas nécessairement.

> Le verbe qui a plusieurs sujets coordonnés se met généralement au pluriel, même si chacun des sujets est au singulier.

[source : reverso.net](http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_1_10_accord_du_verbe_avec_plusiers_sujects_coordonnes.shtml)

Comment: You've said we *need not* put the verb in plural form. But does choosing not to do so change the meaning? Namely, does the first two sentences mean different things to francophones? First one sounds to me(just elementary level learner) as there is an either/or sense, whereas in the second there is not.

Comment: They both mean the same thing. However I personally prefer the first form.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que si l'on écrit distinctement: ''Seulement Bob ou seulement Alice est arrivé ''. Le pluriel commence à partir de DEUX !          On dit bien: ''Ni l'un ni l'autre n'est allé...''

Answer (score 1):

Si le ou est non exclusif, c'est à dire que Bob et Alice ne s'excluent pas l'un l'autre et sont donc susceptibles d'arriver tous les deux, la première proposition est incorrecte.

> Si Bob ou Alice <s>est arrivé</s>.

On écrira par exemple, dans l'hypothèse d'un match de football entre deux pays:

> Si la France ou l'Angleterre **marque** le premier but... (ou exclusif, seule l'une des deux équipes peut marquer ce premier but)
>
> Si la France ou l'Angleterre **marquent** au moins un but... (ou inclusif, les deux équipes peuvent marquer au moins un but).

La question indique que le ou est non exclusif mais la troisième proposition utilise un ou clairement exclusif.