# Peut-on considérer « ou » comme inclusif ?

Tags: sens

Est-il correct de répondre à la question "Es-tu une fille ou un garçon ?" par "oui"  en admettant le "ou" comme inclusif ?

Comment: La question n'est pas claire. Faut-il répondre à « Peut-on considérer « ou » comme inclusif ? » ou bien faut-il répondre à la question : « Dans la question "Es-tu une fille ou un garçon ?" « ou » peut-il être inclusif ?

Comment: Il n'y a guère que dans un contexte de logique formelle (par ex. maths) que 'ou' est systématiquement inclusif. Corollaire : en maths françaises 'positif' signifie >= 0 (alors qu'il veut dire >0 chez les anglo-saxons).

Comment: @MathieuBouville : Pas vraiment d'accord relativement aux maths *"françaises"* : En toute rigueur, positif signifie **>0** en maths françaises aussi. Si on veut *dire* >=0 on dira : *positif **ou nul***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le ***ou*** français peut, suivant le contexte, avoir un sens exclusif ou inclusif.

Exclusif: *Il faut qu'une porte soit ouverte **ou** fermée.* (Alfred de Musset)

Inclusif: *Je cherche un interprète qui parle l'italien **ou** l'espagnol* (s'il parle les deux, on ne va pas le refuser).

Le *ou* inclusif est parfois représenté par *et/ou* pour indiquer clairement que les deux choix ne s'excluent pas l'un l'autre.

Dans une question, ***ou*** a le plus souvent un sens exclusif, c'est à dire que si l'un des termes est vrai, l'autre ou les autres termes sont nécessairement faux et c'est le sens implicite de la question :

> Es-tu une fille ou un garçon ?

La réponse attendue est l'un des deux choix (ex: Une fille). On peut néanmoins parfois répondre ***oui*** à cette question mais dans la grande majorité des cas, ce sera par plaisanterie de logicien et le *ou* aura gardé son sens exclusif :

> **Oui** [ C'est vrai, je suis soit une fille, soit un garçon].

Si aucun des choix proposés n'est considéré comme correct, la réponse pourra être :

> **Non** [ Je ne suis ni une fille, ni un garçon ] (ex: je suis un logiciel d'intelligence artificielle, je suis asexué, etc.).

Dans ce cas, que le *ou* de la question soit exclusif ou inclusif importe peu.

Si l'on souhaite indiquer que l'on se reconnaît dans chacune des deux propositions, on pourra répondre par exemple :

> **Oui**, ça me décrit bien.

Voir aussi :

- [Comment indiquer qu'un « ou » est inclusif?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/528/comment-indiquer-quun-ou-est-inclusif)
- [Exclusivité du « ou » en français](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/15942/exclusivit%C3%A9-du-ou-en-fran%C3%A7ais)
- [Si Bob ou Alice est/sont arrivé(s) ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16821/si-bob-ou-alice-est-sont-arriv%C3%A9s/17725#17725)

Comment: +1 pour la *plaisanterie de logicien* comme j'aime aussi répondre *quoi!* à la pseudo-question *tu es bête ou quoi?* :-)

Answer (score 2):

Dans certains cas, on peut effectivement avoir un "ou" inclusif, si les deux possibilités n'en excluent pas d'autres.

Ce n'est pas le cas dans l'exemple "êtes-vous un garçon ou une fille ?", qui exclut, pour la très grande majorité des locuteurs, d'autres possibilités (sans se lancer dans des digressions philosophiques sur les personnes dont l'identité de genre s'exclut de ces deux catégories - elles répondraient alors plutôt "ni l'un ni l'autre")

Un exemple où le "ou" peut être vu comme inclusif et appeler alors une réponse "oui" simple:

> L'accès est réservé aux membres du club et leurs invités. Etes-vous membre, ou invité par un membre ?
>
> Oui. (On peut aussi compléter alors par "je suis membre", ou "je suis invité")